# ERROR: couldn't create the logfile directory. Logging to the standard output. [Odoo 10 - windows 10]

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]soy nueva en Odoo!. Ya reinicie los servicios pero no entiendo porque me muestra ese ERROR, muchas gracias por la ayuda!.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más seguro es que esté intentando crear el fichero log en el directorio de usuario, para lo cuál no tiene permisos. Prueba a darle una ruta al fichero de logs en la que pueda escribir:

```
./odoo.bin --logfile="%TEMP%\openerp-client.log"
```

En todo caso, mírate cómo configurar los logs en el fichero de configuración de Odoo. No parece ser un problema de programación ni de la base de datos.